# date format is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am converting date as per timezone and i have one more requirement is date format. Now i am getting date in 12/15/14, 5:00 AM format but i want it in “18th Nov. 2014 at 5:15 PM” format.Event I am not getting proper output as per my date format. 
Is this possible in "Objective C".My code is :

```
-(NSString *)dateFormater : (NSString *)dateStr
{
  //NSString *dateStr = @"2014-11-30T21:25:00+00:00";

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
  // [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd MMM,yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssz"];

  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];

  NSLog(@"date : %@",date);


  NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

  NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];


  NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];

  NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];

  NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

  NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 // [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
 [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm a"];

 [dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

 [dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

 [dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

 [dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

 dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];

 NSLog(@"DateString : %@", dateStr);
 return dateStr;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You format string `dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm a` is correct but after setting the format string you are changing it again.
Remove these lines:

```
 [dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

 [dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

---

But in general I would not use a static format string, at least not if you are releasing the app world wide. Since most countries have different localization for presentation purposes you are better of using :

```
dateStr = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I tried your solution but it's sending blank string when i am removing these 2 line..Do you have any other solution for my date format.